# Siblings of `struct task_struct current` always include a process with `pid = 0`

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel

I'm hacking the linux kernel and playing with siblings and children of the `struct task_struct current`.

When outputting the `pid` and command name of siblings, there appears to be a malformed process with `pid` = `0` and the command name is gibberish.

The same thing occurs with the process' parents.

Why is there a process with `pid=0` showing up among the siblings? Isn't that process reserved for `swapper`?

#### Code

```
// Loop over process and parents using something like:

/*
printk("--syscall ## Begin process results ##"); 

printk("--syscall // View children //");
my_list_head = &(current->children);

printk("--syscall // View siblings //");
my_list_head = &(current->sibling)

printk("--syscall results:  ...");
*/


if (my_list_head == NULL) {
  return 0;
}

list_for_each(tempNode, my_list_head) {
  tempTask = list_entry(tempNode, struct task_struct,
          sibling);
  printk("--syscall The %ld-th process's pid is %d and command %s",
         count, tempTask->pid, tempTask->comm);
 }
```

#### Output

<sup>Formatted w/ whitespace</sup>

```
[ 2938.994084] --syscall ## Begin process results ##
[ 2938.994089] --syscall // View children //
[ 2938.994105] --syscall // View siblings //
[ 2938.994116] --syscall The 1-th process's pid is 0 and command \x80ݶE\x96\xff\xff
[ 2938.994133] --syscall results: pid=1400 name=process_ancesto state=0 uid=1000 nvcsw=1 nivcsw=0 num_children=0 num_siblings=1

[ 2938.994139] --syscall ## Begin process results ##
[ 2938.994144] --syscall // View children //
[ 2938.994149] --syscall The 1-th process's pid is 1400 and command process_ancesto
[ 2938.994158] --syscall // View siblings //
[ 2938.994163] --syscall The 1-th process's pid is 0 and command
[ 2938.994176] --syscall results: pid=1282 name=bash state=1 uid=1000 nvcsw=88 nivcsw=18 num_children=1 num_siblings=1

[ 2938.994180] --syscall ## Begin process results ##
[ 2938.994185] --syscall // View children //
[ 2938.994190] --syscall The 1-th process's pid is 1282 and command bash
[ 2938.994198] --syscall // View siblings //
[ 2938.994203] --syscall The 1-th process's pid is 1275 and command systemd
[ 2938.994210] --syscall The 2-th process's pid is 0 and command
[ 2938.994216] --syscall The 3-th process's pid is 117 and command systemd-journal
[ 2938.994222] --syscall The 4-th process's pid is 145 and command systemd-udevd
[ 2938.994227] --syscall The 5-th process's pid is 148 and command systemd-network
[ 2938.994233] --syscall The 6-th process's pid is 369 and command systemd-resolve
[ 2938.994239] --syscall The 7-th process's pid is 370 and command systemd-timesyn
[ 2938.994245] --syscall The 8-th process's pid is 412 and command accounts-daemon
[ 2938.994321] --syscall The 9-th process's pid is 413 and command dbus-daemon
[ 2938.994336] --syscall The 10-th process's pid is 417 and command irqbalance
[ 2938.994346] --syscall The 11-th process's pid is 418 and command rsyslogd
[ 2938.994352] --syscall The 12-th process's pid is 419 and command snapd
[ 2938.994359] --syscall The 13-th process's pid is 420 and command systemd-logind
[ 2938.994365] --syscall The 14-th process's pid is 439 and command cron
[ 2938.994372] --syscall The 15-th process's pid is 451 and command atd
[ 2938.994378] --syscall The 16-th process's pid is 456 and command agetty
[ 2938.994385] --syscall The 17-th process's pid is 461 and command sshd
[ 2938.994390] --syscall The 18-th process's pid is 491 and command unattended-upgr
[ 2938.994397] --syscall The 19-th process's pid is 501 and command polkitd
[ 2938.994413] --syscall results: pid=1200 name=login state=1 uid=0 nvcsw=31 nivcsw=33 num_children=1 num_siblings=19
```

Comment: Not sure if that's the case here, but the kernel has a lot of linked lists that are never empty. That is, the first item always exists and doesn't always have meaning other than serving as the start/end of the list.

Comment: `struct list_head` is used for both actual list heads and for list entries. `&current->children` is an actual list head. `&current->sibling` is a list entry on the `&current->real_parent->children` list. The `list_for_each` macro needs an actual list head, not a list entry.

Comment: ... Specifically `list_entry(tempNode, struct task_struct, sibling)` will not be pointing to a `struct task_struct` when `tempNode` is pointing to the actual list head (which is the parent process's `children` list head).

Comment: @IanAbbott Thanks for your comment. I'm still confused about the difference between an actual `list_head` and just a list entry.

Comment: @IanAbbott ...specifically, if `&current->children` is an actual `list_head`, why would `&current->real_parent->children` not be?

Comment: Lastly,  I used `list_for_each` and a `do..while` loop to count the entries in each and both returned the same count. Is this to be expected? `tempNode = &current->sibling; do { count++; tempNode = tempNode->next; } while (tempNode != &current->sibling)`

Comment: I'm working on an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is an illustration of how two sibling child processes are linked into their parent process's list of children:

```
     PARENT              CHILD 1             CHILD 2
     ======              =======             =======

                         task_struct         task_struct
                        +-------------+     +-------------+
                        |             |     |             |
     task_struct        ~             ~     ~             ~
    +-------------+     |             |     |             |
    |             |     |-------------|     |-------------|
    ~             ~     | children    |     | children    |
    |             |     |             |     |             |
. . |-------------| . . |-------------| . . |-------------| . .
    | children    |     | sibling     |     | sibling     |
X==>| prev | next |<===>| prev | next |<===>| prev | next |<==X
. . |-------------| . . |-------------| . . |-------------| . .
    | sibling     |     |             |     |             |
    |             |     ~             ~     ~             ~
    |-------------|     |             |     |             |
    |             |     +-------------+     +-------------+
    ~             ~
    |             |     'X's are joined together, making
    +-------------+     a doubly linked, circular list.
```

Although `children` and `sibling` are both of type `struct list_head`, `children` is being used as an actual list head (linking to its list of child processes), whereas `sibling` is being used as a list entry.

The parent's `children.next` link points to child 1's `sibling` member, child 1's `sibling.next` link points to child 2's `sibling` member, and child 2's `sibling.next` link points back to the parent's `children` member (the list head). Similarly, the parent's `children.prev` link points to child 2's `sibling` member, child 2's `sibling.prev` link points to child 1's `sibling` member, and child 1's `sibling.prev` link points back to the parent's `children` member.

The `list_for_each(pos, head)` macro visits each node `pos` in the list, starting at `head->next`, while `pos != head`.

Normally, the `head` parameter of `list_for_each(pos, head)` should be an actual list head, but the macro cannot tell the difference between a list head and a list entry. They are both the same type and all the nodes are linked together circularly. (The whole list consists of a list head with zero or more list entries linked in a circle.  For an empty list, the list head just links back to itself.) The `list_for_each` macro will just iterate around the doubly linked list until it get back to where it started.

If `list_for_each(pos, head)` was called with `head` pointing to the parent's `children` member, then `pos` would point to child 1's `sibling` member in the first iteration, and would point to child 2's `sibling` member in the second iteration, and would terminate the loop with `pos` pointing back to the parent's `children` member. Inside the loop, `list_entry(pos, struct task_struct, sibling)` would correctly point to the beginning of the `struct task_struct` for the child process.

Let us say that child 1 is the `current` process. OP's code is using `list_for_each(pos, head)` with `head` pointing to child 1's `sibling` member. Therefore, `pos` would point to child 2's `sibling` member in the first iteration, and would point to the parent's `children` member in the second iteration, and would terminate the loop with `pos` pointing back to child 1's `sibling` member. Inside the loop, `list_entry(pos, struct task_struct, sibling)` would correctly point to the beginning of child 2's `struct task_struct` in the first iteration, but `pos` would point to somewhere before the beginning of the parent's `struct task_struct` in the second iteration. That is the where the problem lies in OP's code.

Comment: So `&current->children` points to a "self-contained" circular list: `child1 -> child2 -> ... -> child1`. On the other hand, `&current->sibling` points to a circular list:  `parentChildren -> child2 --> child 3 -> ... -> parentChildren`? If so, should I be using `list_for_each` to transverse `&current->sibling` siblings?

Comment: @ChrisHappy `&current->children` points to a the head of the circular list of `current`'s children: `current->children` <-> `child1->sibling` <-> `child2->sibling` <-> `...` <-> `current->children`, On the other hand, `&current->sibling` points to some entry of its parent's circular list of its parent's children: `current->sibling` <-> `nextsibling->sibling` <-> `...` <-> `parent->children` <-> `...` <-> `current->sibling`.

Comment: @ChrisHappy You could either transverse the real parent's `children` list and skip the `current->sibling` node, or transverse the `current->sibling` list (which isn't starting at the list head) and skip the real parent's `children` node.